# Uploading Codeigniter project in cpanel

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I changed `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;` to `$config['sess_save_path'] =  sys_get_temp_dir();`

in

> application/config/config.php

and I got this 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/metJr.png)

How to fix this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set your session save path like below

```html
$config['sess_save_path'] =  BASEPATH . 'cache/';
```

Comment: May i get error log data. Is this working on your localhost server? Please share your upload code also.

Comment: Yes it is working on my localhost server. The error is on the link "error" above. Thank you

Comment: I think its your model name convention problem. Please check model name case. Is your model loaded or not?